# Python Histogram ValueError: range parameter must be finite

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

when plotting Pandas dataframe using a histogram,

sample dataframe data

```
     distance
0    5.680195
2    0.000000
3    7.974658
4    2.461387
5    9.703089
```

code I use to plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(df['distance'].values)
plt.show()
```

I have this error

```
"ValueError: range parameter must be finite."
```

my attempt

```
df['Round_Distance'] = df['distance'].round(1)

0    5.7
2    0.0
3    8.0
4    2.5
5    9.7
```

plot again, new error

```
plt.hist(df['Round_Distance'].values)
plt.show()

ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.
```

weird thing is, the work around i use is below, i don't have to ROUND

```
df['distance'].hist(bins=[0,25,50,75,100,125,150,175], color='g')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN cause the issue, i don't need to round it, just drop the NaN, then it works

```
plt.hist(df['distance'].dropna().values)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 18):

Sounds like you have some `NaNs` or `inf` in your actual data. You can select only those values that are finite like this:

```
import numpy as np

df[np.isfinite(df['distance'])]
```

So your plot can be obtained like:

```
plt.hist(df[np.isfinite(df['distance'])].values)
```

Comment: That's strange... shouldn't take a long time. But I can't really help much without seeing more of what is going on. How long does just `df[np.isfinite(df['distance'])]` take? It should be very fast...

Comment: you can create some sample data  with NaNs or inf   then plot to see if that work

Comment: Yeah I did with 10000 points it took a fraction of a second: `df = pd.DataFrame({'distance':np.random.choice(np.concatenate([np.linspace(0,10,1000), np.array([np.nan]), np.array([np.inf])]), 1000000)})`

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to sacul's answer, you can check if you have `NaNs` or `inf` on any of your columns using this:

For `NaNs` :

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

For `inf` :

```
df.max()
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the data does not have

1. Null/None
2. ""/empty string
3. Too many zeros (0)
4. float('inf') or float('-inf')