# My data has no nan but I keep getting the finite error

Tags: python, numpy

**Context**

I am trying to normalise my data to run a ML model. I am using np.log on my data

```
plt.hist(np.log(Portfolio_rtns['Aveva Returns']))
```

I also tried this way:

```
log_Aveva = np.log(Portfolio_rtns['Aveva Returns'])
log_Aveva.hist();
```

But get this error

```
ValueError: supplied range of [-inf, -1.2977785811129585] is not finite
```

I checked my data and even made sure to replace any `nan` values with 0.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642846/python-histogram-valueerror-range-parameter-must-be-finite) which states to use the `np.isfinite`. But I feel as though my data distribution is messed up because of it.

```
Port = np.isfinite(Portfolio_rtns['Aveva Returns'])
plt.hist(np.log(Port));
```

I also ran this function

```
# Square root can also make normal distributed data
plt.hist(np.sqrt(Portfolio_rtns['Aveva Returns']));
```

Though I got the graph, I got this error with it:

```
358: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
```

**Problem**

Is there a problem with my data?

Comment: Log(0) is minus infinity. So even if you feed in finite data, the log will return something with infinities.

Comment: Right, that makes sense.

Comment: And if the square root is giving you an error, you might have negative numbers in your data set too.

Comment: Yeah, its for stocks so that will be in there too. So is there a fix? I need to normalise this data. I tried replacing the `nan` with 0.0001 but the log rule still applies it seem.

Comment: Is there a fix for maths?.... No. The function does what it does. If what it returns is meaningless for you, then you're using the wrong function. As a general rule, Log is typically used on data that is dimensionless, such as rations. I don't know your use case here, but it would make more sense to take the log of new_price/old_price than of new_price-old_price. If you do want the difference, than a linear plot makes the most sense.

Comment: Actually you are right on the latter part. Thanks for that :). I also found that this works log(x+1) https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/methods-to-deal-with-zero-values-while-performing-log-transformation-of-variable/2431/3

Answer (score 0):

So having perused around Coursera, I found that using `log1p` adds 1 to all the zero numbers in the entirety of the data. Also gets rid of the negative. So the solution is:

```
plt.hist(np.log1p(Portfolio_rtns['Aveva Returns']));
```

or

1. `data.describe()` #'data' being your data.
2. Find the minimum of the data
3. Add this minimum to the entirety of the data to convert all zero and negative to positive and more than 0.
4. Run the data
5. After running ML model, convert back to the normal value (this is for the above also)